# Why refresh rate is needed in a passive-matrix LCD?

Tags: pixel-graphics, hardware

In a passive-matrix LCD we have horizontal and vertical conductors. The intersection points are pixels which are  cells of liquid crystal molecules . For drawing a frame, we provide the necessary voltages to specific conductors.
But once we have provided the voltages and the picture has been drawn on the screen ,why do we need to refresh.
As long as the voltage is on ,the picture is still there ....it's not like a CRT where the emission from phosphorus atoms decays.
If the reason is video or animation, then we are changing the frame buffer and then drawing the new frame buffer.
But do we need to refresh the same frame buffer at some rate ?
If so , why ?

Comment: Seems like a "hardware" question to me. This site is more about computer graphics algorithms, programming and software as mentioned on our [help pages](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I vote to close this question because I think it is off-topic here.